# Strategy for Managing Long-Running Tasks in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

We have some logic to calculate an expensive value per user for our ASP.NET Web Forms application. Currently it sits in the `Page_Load` header user control that is on every page like this:

```
//note that we are not awaiting this
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CacheManager.GetExpensiveValue(UserId));
```

And then in the static `CacheManager.GetExpensiveValue(int userID)`:

```
private static object locker = new object();

lock (locker)
{
    if (!AlreadyDone(userID))
    {
        var expensiveValue = ReallyExpensiveMethod(userID);
        //our static cache wrapper class that uses an ObjectCache object
        OurCache.Add(userID, expensiveValue);
    }
    else
    {
        return OurCache.Get(userID);
    }
}
```

This works, but when `ReallyExpensiveMethod()` takes a REALLY long time (I'm also working on improving the performance of the logic behind that), users will block on that `lock` when navigating between pages.

My question is, how could I restructure this to not cause blocking? I've thought about utilizing a ConcurrentDictionary with the values in the dictionary being Task wrappers for `ReallyExpensiveMethod()` and the keys being the UserID to prevent duplicate work, but I'm unsure if that would actually get me anywhere.

We currently are not using any asynchronous logic in this app, and I'm sure the powers-that-be would rather not introduce a change that would require adding `Async="true"` to every single page in the app since this header logic is in every page.

Comment: Can you do it offline (in a separate service at defined intervals)? Or cache perhaps with a timeout?

Comment: @Yahya unfortunately not, as this value needs to be calculated before a user can see certain pages. We adopted this strategy to try to ensure it would be there prior to the user needing to get to the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, how could I restructure this to not cause blocking? ... rather not introduce [asynchrony]

You're between a rock and a hard place, there. Any request has to block or asynchronously wait for the process to complete; there's no other option, unless you can use something like SignalR to send the process results to the client side (but that would probably require significant architectural changes).

That said, you can certainly minimize the effect of the `lock`; it is currently blocking gets for other users if one user is doing the process.

I'm assuming that this calculation is pure (causes no side effects), and that the cache is an in-process, in-memory cache.

In that case, I would cache the task instead of the result. While I'm not wild about parallel processing on ASP.NET, I suppose this would be OK.

I do recommend you use the cache. `ConcurrentDictionary` has similar logic, but no easy way to flush old entries.

So, something like this:

```
// In Page_Load
CacheManager.GetOrAdd(UserID);

Task<Results> CacheManager.GetOrAdd(int userId)
{
  lock (locker)
  {
    if (!OurCache.Contains(userId))
    {
      var task = Task.Run(() => ReallyExpensiveMethod(userId));
      OurCache.Add(userId, task);
      return task;
    }
    else
      return OurCache.Get(userId);
  }
}

// Usage:
Results results = CacheManager.GetOrAdd(UserID).Result;
```

I'm not wild about the blocking (calling `Task<T>.Result` on the last line), but since you don't want to do asynchronous requests you're stuck with that kind of hack.

This code minimizes the time the lock is held. Instead of locking it for the duration of the processing, it is only locked long enough to start the processing on another thread and update the cache.

Comment: An excellent answer; indeed I should have phrased it as "minimize" blocking instead of "prevent" as I am stuck with that for the moment.